# Angular2 ngModel two way binding does not work

Tags: angular, 2-way-object-databinding, ngmodel

I want to bind a model inside a `ngFor` loop to an input field via `ngModel`, but if I add another item to my list the value of the model will be visible in the model, but not in the view.

```
<div *ngFor="let model of models">
    <input [(ngModel)]="model.foo" name="foo">
    {{model | json}}
</div>
<button (click)="addEmptyListItem()">add</button>
```

If I enter `bar` in the view `model | json` will show `{ 'foo': 'bar' }`, now if I add another element to the list `model | json` will still show `{ 'foo': 'bar' }`, but nothing is visible in the input field.

My `models` variable comes from a `BehaviorSubject`

```
private $models: BehaviorSubject<Model[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);
get models(): Model[] { return this.$models.getValue(); }

public addEmptyListItem(): void { 
    let models = this.models();
    models.push(new Model());
    this.$models.next(models);
}
```

which contains a list of `Model`

```
export class Model { public foo: string; }
```

---

Now if I exchange the `[(ngModel)]="model.foo" name="foo"` with `[value]="model.foo" (input)="model.foo = $event.target.value"`:

```
<div *ngFor="let model of models">
    <input [value]="model.foo" (input)="model.foo = $event.target.value">
    {{model | json}}
</div>
<button (click)="addEmptyListItem()">add</button>
```

the view gets updated properly.

#### Question

Is there something I'm overlooking why `[(ngModel)]` isn't working?

And shouldn't `[(ngModel)]` also generate something similar to the above mentioned (see [Two-way data binding in Angular 2](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/13/two-way-data-binding-in-angular-2.html#two-way-data-binding-in-a-nutshell))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `name` attribute has to be unique inside `*ngFor` loop., which you can make with `index`.

Change your code like:

```
<div *ngFor="let model of models;let i = index"">
    <input [(ngModel)]="model.foo" name="foo{{i}}">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Is this documented somewhere - I was searching the angular documentation, but couldn't find this bit of information anywhere?

Comment: this is not actually documented on angular website, but since core concept of angular is to use native HTML attributes\event, So this is actually the behaviour of HTML to have unique name inside form tag., and since ngModel works only after importing FormsModule, so it uses that behaviour., also same we did in `ng-repeat` for angularjs1.x

Comment: Just found a case where `name="foo{{i}}"` is not working - if I want to remove an element from my list (e.g. the first element of a list with 2 elements) and add another element, then the first element will be inside my model but is not displayed in the view (I think because the index changed).

Comment: index will always remain unique, when you delete the element, then name property will change for every element inside *ngFor,

Comment: I followed your example, but it does not work if I delete an element (data not shown) - how can I fix this, or should I just use `[value]="model.foo" (input)="model.foo = $event.target.value"`?

Comment: could you please provide some plunker, so i can help. without looking into code can't say, but that should be done with ngModel too for sure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147347/discussion-between-anoop-and-tobias-helbich).